# Button Refresh Not clearing text

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm making a captcha for my site, nothing fancy and for personal use. My problem is that when i hit the refresh button to bring up a new image in the captcha box it should reset the captcha text box as well.

I am setting it like so

```
   protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is the call that creates a new image   
        FillCaptcha();

        // to clear the text box
        txtCaptcha.Text = String.Empty;

       }
```

When i run the debugger it shows the values entered in the text box and after when its set to "".

Here is the button and text box layout

```
    <asp:TableRow>
     <asp:TableCell>
                Enter Below Captcha Code :
     </asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TableCell>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
         </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
          <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="middle">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
                </asp:ScriptManager>       
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height: 50px; width:120px; border:solid; border-color:blue; text-align:center;">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td valign="middle">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow> `
```

Ive search on Stack for some time and everyone seems to be setting it as i have it. I have the same call to the `txtCaptcha.Text = String.Empty;` in another function and it works fine. any help would be grateful. If I'm unclear about something let me know and ill do my best to better explain it.

[Captcha layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVGMB.png)

Comment: `txtCaptcha.Text` is outside the UpdatePanel. Move it inside.

Comment: Are you sure the `txtCaptcha.Text = String.Empty;` line is being hit?

Comment: @VDWWD trying that now.

Comment: @Chris Pickford I set break points to see if it was and it was being hit.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for the help it makes sense now. wish i could give you  points some how.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Comment: why did i get down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `TextBox` inside `UpdatePanel`. Like So:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ScriptManager>       
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 50px; width:120px; border:solid; border-color:blue; text-align:center;">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Read about [Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Comment: Ya i read that and didn't understand how textboxes were laid out. I'm new to ASP.NET. Its crazy how picky/tricky it is sometimes